# RavenDB clicking the "Add Reduce" button does nothing

Tags: ravendb

I'm working through the RavenDB series on Tekpub, trying to do the same on my machine as what is going on in the videos.  I'm creating the index as Oren has, with the Maps section as follows:

```
from user in docs.Users
from Tag in user.FavoriteTags
select new { Tag, Count = 1 }
```

However, when I click the "Add Reduce" button, nothing happens...nothing...it's like the click event has not registered.  Any pointers as to why this may be?

Comment: What build are you using? Can you check using a recent build (unstable)?

Comment: That was on Build 616.  I've posted the same question to the RavenDB Group, where another user experienced the same problem on build 647 (latest unstable build).

Comment: same here. On 616, running as a windows service (in case that matters), clicking the Reduce button will not do anything.

Comment: also just tried 647 and same thing. Even deleting the Reduce from an existing sample index and trying to click Add Reduce again wont do a thing.

Comment: We have two machines here with identical configuration (same version Chrome and Silverlight, both Win 7 x64). One works, one doesn't. Running on the same 658 build of RavenDB.

Answer (score 0):

Just started to investigate this problem with @kfuglsang and we found that installing:

Silverlight toolkit
- http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528

Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime for Windows 32-bit
- http://www.silverlight.net/downloads

on my Windows 7 x64 with Chrome v. 17 and IE 9, solved the problem.

However, we cannot account for this solution, but only observe that it seems to work.

Comment: Btw., the issue is registered at RavenDB's issue tracker here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-78